# How to merge www.example.com and example.com on google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

I am new to Google AdSense. I have a small website (let's call it `www.example.com`). Unfortunately, AdSense handles `www.example.com` and `example.com` separately (different stats). How can I merge these in AdSense?

I saw some documentation about implementing a 301, but now really sure how this would help. After all, both `www.example.com` and `example.com` do get me to the same site/page already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the same page in your browser but technically they are different URLs and thus different pages. Do the 301 redirect from one to the other, it doesn't matter which, so you are consistently on the same URL and thus getting consistent stats as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have redirected `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com` (www.). I'll check in the coming days.